# How to change back colour in listview dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm creating winforms app which serves to Host monitoring in my network. I'm pinging IP adresses and results of ping are shown in listview (Host Ip address, delay time, description of host).

How I can change dynamically back colour of device shown in list view when this device is TIMEOUT?

This is code of my MAIN Form:

```
public partial class MainFrm : Form
{
    private string XmlPath;
    private Checker Checker;
    private ResourceManager _rm;
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

    public MainFrm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _rm = new ResourceManager("HostMonitor.Resources", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        //assign events to dataset
        hosts.Groups.TableNewRow += new DataTableNewRowEventHandler(Groups_TableNewRow);
        hosts.Groups.GroupsRowChanged += new HostsData.GroupsRowChangeEventHandler(Groups_GroupsRowChanged);
        hosts.Groups.GroupsRowDeleted += new HostsData.GroupsRowChangeEventHandler(Groups_GroupsRowDeleted);

        hosts.Hosts.TableNewRow += new DataTableNewRowEventHandler(Hosts_TableNewRow);
        hosts.Hosts.HostsRowChanged += new HostsData.HostsRowChangeEventHandler(Hosts_HostsRowChanged);


        XmlPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath));
        XmlPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(XmlPath), "hosts.xml");

        XmlPath=Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), "hosts.xml");

        hosts.ReadXml(XmlPath);

        DataRelation rel = new DataRelation("HostsInGroup", hosts.Groups.Columns["GroupName"], hosts.Hosts.Columns["Group"]);
        hosts.Relations.Add(rel);

        LoadData();

        //start pinging
        Checker = new Checker(comps, this);
        Checker.Start();

    }

    void Hosts_HostsRowChanged(object sender, HostsData.HostsRowChangeEvent e)
    {
        HostsData.HostsRow row = (HostsData.HostsRow)e.Row;
        foreach (ListViewItem item in comps.Items)
        {                
            if (item.Tag == row)
            {
                item.Text = row.HostName;
                item.SubItems[2].Text = row.Description;
                if ((item.Group == null) || (item.Group.Header != row.Group))
                {
                    foreach (ListViewGroup gr in comps.Groups)
                    {
                        if (gr.Header == row.Group)
                        {
                            item.Group = gr;
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }
                break;


            }
        }
    }

    void Hosts_TableNewRow(object sender, DataTableNewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        HostsData.HostsRow row = (HostsData.HostsRow)e.Row;
        ListViewGroup group = null;
        if (row.Group!="")
        {
            foreach (ListViewGroup gr in comps.Groups)
            {
                if (gr.Header == row.Group)
                {
                    group = gr;
                    break;
                }
            } 
        }

        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(group);
        item.Text = row.HostName;
        item.Tag = row;
        item.SubItems.Add("");
        item.SubItems.Add(row.Description);
        comps.Items.Add(item);
    }

    void Groups_GroupsRowDeleted(object sender, HostsData.GroupsRowChangeEvent e)
    {
        HostsData.GroupsRow row = (HostsData.GroupsRow)e.Row;
        foreach (ListViewGroup gr in comps.Groups)
        {
            if (gr.Tag == row)
            {
                comps.Groups.Remove(gr);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    void Groups_GroupsRowChanged(object sender, HostsData.GroupsRowChangeEvent e)
    {
        HostsData.GroupsRow row = (HostsData.GroupsRow)e.Row;
        foreach (ListViewGroup gr in comps.Groups)
        {
            if (gr.Tag == row)
            {
                gr.Header = row.GroupName;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    void Groups_TableNewRow(object sender, DataTableNewRowEventArgs e)
    {            
        ListViewGroup gr = new ListViewGroup();
        HostsData.GroupsRow row = (HostsData.GroupsRow)e.Row;
        gr.Header = row.GroupName;
        gr.Tag = row;
        comps.Groups.Add(gr);
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        comps.Items.Clear();
        comps.Groups.Clear();

        foreach (HostsData.GroupsRow group in hosts.Groups)
        {
            ListViewGroup gr = new ListViewGroup();
            gr.Header = group.GroupName;
            gr.Tag = group;
            comps.Groups.Add(gr);                
            foreach (HostsData.HostsRow host in group.GetChildRows("HostsInGroup"))
            {
                ListViewItem ht = new ListViewItem(gr);
                ht.Text = host.HostName;
                ht.SubItems.Add("---");
                ht.SubItems.Add(host.Description);
                ht.Tag = host;
                comps.Items.Add(ht);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is code of my class Checker:

```
public class Checker
{
    private class CheckHostEventArgs:EventArgs
    {
        private string _hostname;            
        private ListViewItem _item;            

        public string HostName
        {
            get { return _hostname;}
        }           

        public ListViewItem Item
        {
            get { return _item;}               
        }


        public CheckHostEventArgs(string HostName, ListViewItem item)
        {
            _hostname=HostName;
            _item=item;
        }
    }

    private delegate PingReply CheckHost(CheckHostEventArgs e);
    private delegate ListViewItem[] GetCompsDelegate();

    private ListView _list;
    private MainFrm _frm;
    private int AsyncCount = 0;
    private Thread _thread;
    private ResourceManager _rm;

    public Checker(ListView list,MainFrm form)
    {
        _rm = new ResourceManager("HostMonitor.Resources", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        _list = list;
        _frm = form;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _thread = new Thread(Main);
        _thread.Start();
    }


    private void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                OneLoop();
                Int64 time = Environment.TickCount + Config.Interval;
                while (Environment.TickCount < time)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
            return;                
        }
    }

    private void OneLoop()
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in GetComps())
        {
            HostsData.HostsRow host = (HostsData.HostsRow)item.Tag;

            //eliminujemy nieaktywne hosty
            if (host.HostName == "")
            {

                continue;
            }
            if (!host.Active)
            {
                continue;
            }
            HostsData.GroupsRow group = (HostsData.GroupsRow)item.Group.Tag;
            if (!group.Active)
            {
                continue;
            }

            //sprawdzamy aktywne hosty
            lock (this)
            {
                if (AsyncCount < Config.MaxAsyncPings)
                {
                    AsyncCount++;
                    CheckHost del = new CheckHost(Check);
                    CheckHostEventArgs e = new CheckHostEventArgs(host.HostName, item);
                    del.BeginInvoke(e, new AsyncCallback(CheckCallback), item);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private PingReply Check(CheckHostEventArgs e)
    {
        Ping p = new Ping();
        try
        {
            return p.Send(e.HostName, Config.Timeout);
        }
        catch
        {

            return null;
        }


    }

    private void CheckCallback(IAsyncResult asResult)
    {
        if (asResult.IsCompleted)
        {
            if (_frm.InvokeRequired)
            {
                AsyncCallback del = new AsyncCallback(CheckCallback);
                _frm.Invoke(del, asResult);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    AsyncResult ar = (AsyncResult)asResult;
                    CheckHost del = (CheckHost)ar.AsyncDelegate;
                    PingReply r = del.EndInvoke(asResult);
                    ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)ar.AsyncState;
                    if (r != null)
                    {                            
                        switch (r.Status)
                        {
                            case IPStatus.Success:
                                item.SubItems[1].Text = String.Format("{0}", r.RoundtripTime);
                                break;
                            default:
                                item.SubItems[1].Text = r.Status.ToString();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        item.SubItems[1].Text = _rm.GetString("CheckerErrorOccured");
                    }
                }
                catch
                {}
                lock (this)
                {
                    AsyncCount--;
                }                    
            }                
        }
    }

    private ListViewItem[] GetComps()
    {
        if (_frm.InvokeRequired)
        {
            GetCompsDelegate d = new GetCompsDelegate(GetComps);
            return (ListViewItem[])_frm.Invoke(d);
        }
        else
        {
            ListViewItem[] result=new ListViewItem[_list.Items.Count];
            _list.Items.CopyTo(result, 0);
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _thread.Abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does an event get fired when it times out?

Comment: No. I want something like that: http://vpx.pl/i/2017/04/07/img1.jpg. When i've got Timeout in field "Czas odpowiedzi" i want to change backcolour of this item.

Comment: Does it automatically update the value in your program? Does it keep checking the db? You need an event so don't say `No. I want blabla`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the background color of an item in a listview with code like this:

```
        if (timedout)
            listview1.Items[row].BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
        else //reset the color
            listview1.Items[row].BackColor = listview1.BackColor;
```

Also since your checker is running on a different thread than your main form, you'll have to put this code in a separate function and call it with an invoke.